# Is it possible to import FBX and "Update Animation"?

Tags: animation, import, .fbx

There's a feature inside 3D Studio Max that allows you to import an FBX file and "Update Animation" so that if you're importing with an existing rig in the scene, instead of bringing in the bones, it updates the existing ones to copy the animation data.
I can't find the option with a regular FBX import in Blender so I'm wondering if anyone knows an equivalent.

Thanks!

Comment: See if [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPCYam8mgok) tutorial about using animations from Mixamo helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link. So yeah, it looks like re-targeting is the only way to do it? The reason I was hoping for Update Animation is there are no steps. It's a one-click solution. But re-targeting looks simple enough in Blender so I'll follow it for now :)

Comment: You can also use the [animation library](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXGKDG1BeW4) in Blender 3.0. Not too sure about the tutorial though! :^)

Comment: Yeah the tutorial was a good starting point. Using the NLA editor is definitely a great way to transfer the animation from one rig to another, now I'm just trying to figure out how to collapse it down into a single file so I can delete the old rig and export to UE4. I've been using 3dsMax for 20+ years so learning blender is quite different but man this software is amazing.

Comment: Yes is possible. Try this good video tutorial from youtube: [How to combine and edit Mixamo animations in Blender?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fLfjHzJy2A0)